# how to get count of rows with condition having group by

Tags: mysql, count

i want to get count of rows who's amount is  **> 0**

with out count function my query

```
   SELECT pd.student_admission_id,

    sum(fcm.fee_amount)- coalesce((SELECT sum(ft.amount_paid) FROM   fee_transactions ft  where ft.student_id=pd.student_admission_id GROUP BY     ft.student_id), 0)  as due_amount

FROM fee_class_mapping fcm INNER JOIN student_present_class_details pd ON pd.class_id = fcm.class_id  GROUP BY  pd.student_admission_id;
```

**result**

```
+----------------------+------------+
| student_admission_id | due_amount |
+----------------------+------------+
|                    1 |          0 |
|                    2 |      12000 |
|                    3 |      12000 |
+----------------------+------------+
```

i want to get count of who's **due_amount is  > 0**

how to write count function with above query ?

can any one help me out ?. thank you!.

Comment: Just add at the end: having count( sum(fcm.fee_amount)- coalesce((SELECT sum(ft.amount_paid) ) >0

Comment: it gives error can you please post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first query you could rewrite it with joins like

```
SELECT pd.student_admission_id,
       SUM(fcm.fee_amount) - COALESCE(ft.amount_paid, 0)  AS due_amount
FROM student_present_class_details pd
INNER JOIN fee_class_mapping fcm  ON pd.class_id = fcm.class_id 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT student_id,SUM(ft.amount_paid) amount_paid 
    FROM   fee_transactions
    GROUP BY student_id
) ft ON ft.student_id=pd.student_admission_id 
GROUP BY  pd.student_admission_id
```

To get the count where due_amount > 0 you could wrap the above query as a sub query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT pd.student_admission_id,
           SUM(fcm.fee_amount) - COALESCE(ft.amount_paid, 0)  AS due_amount
    FROM student_present_class_details pd
    INNER JOIN fee_class_mapping fcm  ON pd.class_id = fcm.class_id 
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT student_id,SUM(ft.amount_paid) amount_paid 
        FROM   fee_transactions
        GROUP BY student_id
    ) ft ON ft.student_id=pd.student_admission_id 
    GROUP BY  pd.student_admission_id
) t
WHERE t.due_amount > 0
```